# How can I listen in on shortcuts when the app is the task bar in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

An example of an app that does this is [Enso](http://www.humanized.com/enso/), it pops up when you press the caps lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can act on global hotkeys by calling the winapi function [RegisterHotKey](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html). Also see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4345/NET-system-wide-hotkey-component and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3055/System-Hotkey-Component for example. You can not use all key combination as hotkeys. For those that don't work you might try a global keyboard hook (SetWindowsHookEx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a hook in user32.dll. Lookup the Win32-API call SetWindowsHookEx. You can call it from C# via the stuff in System.Runtime.InteropServices.

[This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante) discusses the topic nicely.

**Edit**: Lars Truijens answer looks like a nicer approach actually.